# Advanced tag filter mail notifications cannot be stopped

Tags: bug, tags, notifications, email

Some days ago I configured an advanced tag filter from this page (see the red rectangle).

[image: screen shot]

I added few tags from different Stack Exchange sites. I also configured email notification for three hours.

The next day I decided I am not satisfied with the results and decided to remove the filter alltogether. So I deleted it. However, the email notifications persist. Shouldn't one be automatically unsubscribed from the filter once he removes it?

Comment: How long has it been since you removed the filter? It's not unreasonable to think that the stop wouldn't be instant. Also isn't there an "unsubscribe" link at the bottom of the email?

Comment: @cai - three days and it has not stopped. As for the unsubscribe link - I have used it about the time I posted my question and I have not received any mail updates since. Still, I would expect unsubscribing from an email would not be needed if I have removed the filter altogether.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev - I agree with your question;  another phrasing could be: Is there a legitimate case for removing a filter and staying subscribed to the emails?   If not why is the behavior disconnected.